# User Life Cycle SQL Query Logic in Snowflake

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, window-functions

I am working on building a query to track the life cycle of an user through the platform via events. The table `EVENTS` has 3 columns USER_ID, DATE_TIME and EVENT_NAME. Below is a snapshot of the table,

[image]

My query should return the below result (the first timestamp for the registered event followed by the immediate/next timestamp of the following log_in event and finally followed by the immediate/next timestamp of the final landing_page event),

[image]

Below is my query ,

```
WITH FIRST_STEP AS
(SELECT 
USER_ID,
MIN(CASE WHEN EVENT_NAME = 'registered' THEN DATE_TIME ELSE NULL END) AS REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP
FROM EVENTS
GROUP BY 1
),
SECOND_STEP AS
(SELECT * FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'log_in'
ORDER BY DATE_TIME
),
THIRD_STEP AS
(SELECT * FROM EVENTS
WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'landing_page'
ORDER BY DATE_TIME
)
SELECT
a.USER_ID,
a.REGISTERED_TIMESTAMP,
(SELECT
CASE WHEN b.DATE_TIME >= a.REGISTRATIONS_TIMESTAMP THEN b.DATE_TIME END AS LOG_IN_TIMESTAMP
FROM SECOND_STEP
LIMIT 1
),
(SELECT
CASE WHEN c.DATE_TIME >= LOG_IN_TIMESTAMP THEN c.DATE_TIME END AS LANDING_PAGE_TIMESTAMP
FROM THIRD_STEP
LIMIT 1
)
FROM FIRST_STEP AS a
LEFT JOIN SECOND_STEP AS b ON a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN THIRD_STEP AS c ON b.USER_ID = c.USER_ID;
```

Unfortunately I am getting the "SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" error when I try to run the query

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

The pattern you are looking for is `register anything* login anything* landing` and the measures are the `min(iff(event_name='x', date_time, null))` for each.

Check:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/funnel-analytics-with-sql-match-recognize-on-snowflake-8bd576d9b7b1
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/match-recognize-introduction.html

Set the output to `one row per match`.

Untested sample query:

```sql
select *
from data
match_recognize(
    partition by user_id
    order by date_time
    measures min(iff(event_name='register', date_time, null)) as t1
      , min(iff(event_name='log_in', date_time, null)) as t2
      , min(iff(event_name='landing_page', date_time, null)) as t3
    one row per match
    pattern(register anything* login anything* landing)
    define
        register as event_name = 'register'
        , login as event_name = 'log_in'
        , landing as event_name = 'landing_page'
);
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM EVENTS
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY USER_ID
    ORDER BY DATE_TIME
    MEASURES MIN(IFF(EVENT_NAME='registered', DATE_TIME, NULL)) AS REGISTER_TIMESTAMP,
                       MIN(IFF(EVENT_NAME='log_in', DATE_TIME, NULL)) AS LOG_IN_TIMESTAMP,
                        MIN(IFF(EVENT_NAME='landing_page', DATE_TIME, NULL)) AS LANDING_PAGE_TIMESTAMP
    ONE ROW PER MATCH
    PATTERN(STEP_1  STEP_2 STEP_3)
    DEFINE
          STEP_1 AS EVENT_NAME='registered',
          STEP_2 AS EVENT_NAME='log_in',
          STEP_3 AS EVENT_NAME='landing_page'
);

Comment: Is there a way that I can modify the PATTERN and DEFINE logic or the MEASURES logic in the query to achieve what I want from my table (to return the first timestamp for the first event, followed by the immediate/next timestamp of the second event, followed by the immediate/next timestamp of the third event and so on in the funnel)?

Comment: The number of records in my result set keep changing when I run my query each time

Comment: And how can we deal with missing events in a user's flow? if any any event is missing in the user flow through the funnel the query doesn't return any result as the pattern search fails when the event defined is missing in the user flow

Comment: Post a new question with sample data and desired results, and you'll get the answers that the questions ask

Comment: Thanks! Below is the link to the question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626707/funnel-analytics-using-sql-in-snowflake